# why doesnt Excel.Application.Quit(); work for me?

Tags: c#, office-interop

```
while (updating) {
  Excel.Application excel1 = new Excel.Application();
  sheet = excel1.Workbooks.Open(from_file, UpdateLinks: 1, ReadOnly: true);
  excel1.ActiveWorkbook.XmlMaps[1].ExportXml(out xmlData_s);
  excel1.ActiveWorkbook.XmlMaps[2].ExportXml(out xmlData_c);
  sheet.Close(0);
  excel1.Quit();
  await Task.Delay(10000);    
}
```

Question 1) Why doesn't it close excel? Below is a picture of my task manager after 10 seconds of that while loop running. It just keeps opening more and more Excel apps and not closing them when done.

[image: task manager after 10 seconds]

Question 2) `await Task.Delay(10000)` seems to do the same as `await Task.Delay(9999999999999)`. Why?

Comment: you are not doing anything after the await Task.Delay(...), so the delay time will not make any difference.

Comment: not sure, but for 1) could you try to add : `System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excel1);` after the Quit() ?

Comment: Please keep in mind that you have to manually dispose all interop objects

Comment: JonasH no its at the bottom of the loop.
Pac0 ill try, whats the difference?

Comment: .NET uses RCWs (runtime callable wrapper objects) to talk to Excel, those objects need to be collected so Excel knows it can stop running.  Most important thing to do here is to move new Excel.Application() out of the loop, one is enough.  Then just keep doing useful things afterwards to trigger a collection.  Including terminating the program.